# Just upgraded my hadoop cluster to 2.4.1 and things arent working correctly

Tags: java, apache, web-services, hadoop

After configuring the nodes and running the start-all.sh, all the nodes say they are starrted but looking at the nodes for the slave nodes i see the following in the logs:

```
2014-08-05 06:41:05,790 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2014-08-05 06:41:05,791 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8010: starting
2014-08-05 06:41:14,604 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Data-node version: -55 and name-node layout version: -56
2014-08-05 06:41:14,711 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Lock on /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 4796@hadoop03
2014-08-05 06:41:14,997 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Analyzing storage directories for bpid BP-633751026-127.0.1.1-1407152865456
2014-08-05 06:41:14,997 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Locking is disabled
2014-08-05 06:41:15,025 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Restored 0 block files from trash.
2014-08-05 06:41:15,211 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Setting up storage: nsid=298887827;bpid=BP-633751026-127.0.1.1-1407152865456;lv=-55;nsInfo=lv=-56;cid=CID-a343ba30-a7b$
2014-08-05 06:41:15,231 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util: Path /hadoop/hdfs/namenode should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
2014-08-05 06:41:15,233 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Added volume - /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current, StorageType: DISK
2014-08-05 06:41:15,293 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Registered FSDatasetState MBean
2014-08-05 06:41:15,296 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DirectoryScanner: Periodic Directory Tree Verification scan starting at 1407257140296 with interval 21600000
2014-08-05 06:41:15,296 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Adding block pool BP-633751026-127.0.1.1-1407152865456
2014-08-05 06:41:15,297 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Scanning block pool BP-633751026-127.0.1.1-1407152865456 on volume /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current...
2014-08-05 06:41:15,484 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Time taken to scan block pool BP-633751026-127.0.1.1-1407152865456 on /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/curren$
2014-08-05 06:41:15,484 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Total time to scan all replicas for block pool BP-633751026-127.0.1.1-1407152865456: 188ms
2014-08-05 06:41:15,484 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Adding replicas to map for block pool BP-633751026-127.0.1.1-1407152865456 on volume /hadoop/hdfs/$
2014-08-05 06:41:15,484 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Time to add replicas to map for block pool BP-633751026-127.0.1.1-1407152865456 on volume /hadoop/$
2014-08-05 06:41:15,484 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Total time to add all replicas to map: 0ms
2014-08-05 06:41:15,486 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool BP-633751026-127.0.1.1-1407152865456 (Datanode Uuid null) service to /192.168.0.5:8020 beginning handshake $
2014-08-05 06:41:30,664 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool BP-633751026-127.0.1.1-1407152865456 (Datanode Uuid null) service to /192.168.0.$
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager.registerDatanode(DatanodeManager.java:806)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.registerDatanode(FSNamesystem.java:4240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.registerDatanode(NameNodeRpcServer.java:992)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.registerDatanode(DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.DatanodeProtocolProtos$DatanodeProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(DatanodeProtocolProtos.java:28057)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)
```

Can anyone offer any insight into what is going on in my cluster?
I can provide full configuration files and info if it is required.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your configuration files also, after updating hadoop to 2.4.1 in every node?
If you did, can you provide log files and configuration files.
I think the issue is with initializing hadoop data files property in core-site.xml

Comment: I built the hadoop 2.4.1 version from src and made one set of files to distribute to the cluster. All the settings across the nodes is consistent with the master as close as i can tell.

Comment: Once delete the filesystem in every DataNode and format the NameNode.
I think your DataNodes still referring to old NameNode